# How to enable Airwatch Tunnel in Xamarin.Forms WebView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, airwatchsdk

I have a WebView in my Xamarin.Forms app. Followed instructions [here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workspace-ONE-UEM/1810/vmware-airwatch-guides-1810/GUID-AW1810-SDK_Plugin_Xamarin.html) to integrate AirWatch SDK into my iOS App.

I have also added an SDK profile to the IPA via AirWatch console. The profile has been configured to use AirWatch tunnel when accessing a corporate resource.

However, I get a 403 (Forbidden) response when trying to navigate to the URL.

Am I missing any setup?

Comment: Can you  provide the URL? If he starts with HTTP ,you should set your application allow HTTP access.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I am trying to access corporate URLs that start with https://

Comment: So ,can you provide the url ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFTunfortunately not. This is an internal only URL behind corporate firewall.